# JavaScript modules hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, module

I can't believe I haven't found an answer to this question anywhere.

So, is there any kind of module hierarchy in JavaScript (EcmaScript 6 also)?
So that a module can contain another modules.
Or that modules are contained inside packages, and packages can contain another packages?

Comment: code may imports modules (may) imports modules imports modules...

Comment: @Jonas w, I didn't understand that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that modules are contained inside packages?

Well partly. Theres no package as it isnt necessary. This can be done easily with folders and nested requires.

E.g. you have an *auth folder* containing *User.js* and *Admin.js* , then you can bundle it with a *index.js* :

```
module.exports={
  Admin:require("Admin.js"),
  User:require("User.js")
};
```

Now you could load the *"package"* like this:

```
var auth=require("auth");
auth.User.login("sth");
```

So there is no package in JS but it can be easily made with nested requires. ( the upper code uses NodeJS style, you may use *import* instead of *require*).

> So is there a module hirarchy?

Yes based on how they *require* each other.